# What exactly is this Lego train motor?

Tags: part-identification, trains

I bought this in the early 90s as a spare, since the type of Lego train was being phased out. Presumably the old 12V system.  The original train was given away but I still have this.  I want to sell it but need to know what it is.  It has the numbers 49 5 on the bottom.[image]

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be [Electric, Train Motor 12V Modern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb12v).